# ROS Qt Interrupted System Call On Plugin Startup

Tags: thread, plugin, pyqt, joystick, startup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently been working on a python widget for `rqt` that creates a separate thread to read joystick data in from a pipe. I've tested it as a standalone python program and confirmed that it's getting valid data. However, when I put it into a python plugin for `rqt` that I've already created and tested, it crashes. After some tweaking of the code, it looks like it crashes at the end of the `__init__` function in the plugin with `IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call`  when the pipe read is interrupted.

The initialization is basically:

1. Create a joystick object that creates a thread to endlessly read in data from `/dev/input/js0`; start running it
2. Create thread to endlessly check the Joystick object containing this other thread to look for new data; start running it
3. Wait 5 seconds, during which joystick data prints out fine as I would expect
4. The 5 Second wait ends, `IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call` is thrown, and `rqt` loads as normal

A snippet of the plugin code is below. The Joystick class being referenced creates a thread in the same manner, opens a pipe using `self._pipe = open('/dev/local/js0', 'r')`, then reads in raw data for parsing using `for character in self._pipe.read(1):`

```
    class Joystick(Plugin):
      # Variables...
      def __init__(self, context):
          # Some initialization code here...
          #...
          # Create the joystick object and run its thread
          self._joystick_reader = LinuxJoystickReader()
          self._joystick_reader.initialize('/dev/input/js0')
          self._joystick_reader.start()
          # Create a local thread and run it to print the joystick data
          self._joystick_thread_run = True
          self._joystick_read_thread = Thread(target=self.pub_joystick, args=())
          self._joystick_read_thread.start()
          # Sleep, during which the data prints out fine
          time.sleep(5)
          # -- ERROR --
          # File "joystick_class.py" line 35, in read_pipe
          # for character in self._pipe.read(1):
          # IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call

       def pub_joystick(self):
         while self._joystick_thread_run:
           if self._joystick_reader.has_new_data():
             pub_str = str(self._joystick_reader.get_data_array()[0]) + ", " + str(self._joystick_reader.get_data_array()[1])
             print pub_str
         self._joystick_reader.stop()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67456/ros-qt-interrupted-system-call-on-plugin-startup/) by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-17**:
Btw you should never sleep during construction but I guess this is just part of your debugging code. Even any long running other operation should be deferred or be performed in a separate thread.

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2013-07-18**:
Yes, the sleep is just for debugging purposes (a shot in the dark that paid off), I'm trying to get the separate threads to run on their own without crashing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like something in Qt or one of the plugins was interrupting the system call I was making to read the joystick input. Adding additional try/catch code to my joystick implementation solved the problem for me, since it can just continue reading input even if it is interrupted. I was also able to get my plugin working without crashing and without the additional try/catch code by adding my plugin to the GUI last, after all the other plugins were loaded and running.

Got the idea from [this StackOverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763740/pyqt4-interrupted-system-call-while-calling-commands-getoutput-in-timer). I'm still not sure what part interrupted my system call, why it did that, or if it's intentional, but the solution seems to be robust to random interruptions on startup.

---

Originally posted by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) with karma: 115 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based in the code block you posted I can't spot the problem. But I tried a simple example which works fine for me (including the cleanup).

```
class MyPlugin(Plugin):

def __init__(self, context):
        super(MyPlugin, self).__init__(context)
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self.cb, args=())
        self._thread_running = True
        self._thread.start()

    def cb(self):
        while self._thread_running:
            print 'cb'
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print('thread finished')

    def shutdown_plugin(self):
        self._thread_running = False
        self._thread.join()
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2